# Почему генерируется странный проект с ошибкой?

Tags: android, android-studio

**Проблема:** сегодня скачал новую *Android Studio 1.5*. Создал два проекта: первый создался нормально, а второй... с кучей нового кода и ошибкой рендеринга. Создавал обычный `Blank Activity`.

В результате получил такой класс `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            //Обычно, вот этот код не генерируется!!!
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            //И этот тоже
            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

`main_activity`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.dugin_rostislav.mynewapplication.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

От куда вообще весь код макета взялся для меня непонятно. Обычно генерировался только `RelativeLayout` с `TextView`. В добавок к непонятному макету получил ошибку:

> The graphics preview in the layout editor may not be accurate: 
>   - PorterDuff Color Filters are not supported.

**Вопрос:** от куда взялось столько кода и как сделать, чтобы, при создании `Blank Activity` — я получал обычный `Blank Activity`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Blank Activity` - шаблон который содержит элементы `material design`.

Просто добавляйте `Empty Activity`.

Comment: А ошибка рендеринга от куда? Что с ней делать?

Comment: @bukashka101, Скорее всего из за того что проект сперва нужно собрать, после должно зарендериться.

Comment: В моем понимании "собрать", означает скомпилировать в .apk. Что-то мне подсказывает, что Вы имеете что-то другое ввиду?)

Comment: Да, скомпилировать

Comment: Хм... Завтра попробую. Спасибо :).

Comment: @bukashka101, Еще может быть выбран API level, который у вас не установлен в SDK Mangager, поэтому и не рендрит.

Comment: Я поставил API 15, он точно есть.

Comment: Я вынесу в отдельный вопрос. Кстати, программа работает, но появились новые ошибки...

Comment: если ошибка рендеринга отображается в Preview - достаточно в стилях перед названием темы добавить `Base`. Например:  `parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"`. А вообще - сама ошибка влияет ТОЛЬКО на preview.

Comment: Для более хорошего понимания лучше вообще все делать руками, начиная от создания Java класса и унаследования его от класса Activity до переопределения метода оnCreate (Ctrl+O) и привязки созданного и унаследованного класса к Вашему заранее созданному лэйату через `SetContentView(R.layout.your_layuot_name)`